# Displying data in gridview using jQuery ajax call is too slow

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview and a button. On button click am binding data to gridview using jQuery ajax call. below is the code.

I followed the code as explained in this link
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/03/bind-data-to-gridview-with-jquery-or.html

1. I am fetching data into DataTable from database
2. Taking Datatable data into List object by looping each row of a datatable
3. returning this List to .cs STATIC WEBMETHOD and this also returning same LIST
4. I am .cs WEBMETHOD on button click through jQuery ajax and appending list data to gridview as shown below.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "ManualReconJS.aspx/GetRemarkHistory",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        sAppId: sAppId,
        sTempl: sTempl,
        sUserId: sUserId,
        sSrno: sSrno
    }),
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#imgModalRemarks").show();
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $('#gvRemarksHistory').empty();

        var tempDataHtml = "";
        if (result.d.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
                tempDataHtml = "";
                if (i == 0) {
                    var items = result.d[i].toString().split(',');
                    tempDataHtml += "<tr>";
                    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                        tempDataHtml += "<th>" + items[j] + "</th>";
                    }
                    tempDataHtml += "</tr>";
                } else {
                    var items = result.d[i].toString().split(',');
                    tempDataHtml += "<tr>";
                    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                        tempDataHtml += "<td>" + items[j] + "</td>";
                    }
                    tempDataHtml += "</tr>";
                }

                $("#gvRemarksHistory").append(tempDataHtml);
            }
        } else {
            $("#imgModalRemarks").hide();
            alert('Remarks history not found.');
        }
        $("#imgModalRemarks").hide();
    },
    error: function(result) {
        var err = $(result.responseText).filter('title').text();
        alert("Message: " + err);
        $("#imgModalRemarks").hide();
    }
});
return false;
```

My requirement is to display remarks in gridview. Above code working fine and fast when remarks data is too less. I am having problem on when the data is in large amount. Suppose I have more than 10000 records and I have implemented paging logic (1000 per page) also. While page load am displaying first 1000 remarks and on next click am displaying another 1000 remarks like that ... but each and every next/prev click data fetching is very very slow and in each click my page is gets hanged till the process complete.

Please suggest me the best ways to fetch and display the data on to grid.
How can make it fast? Fetching data from database is very fast(in milliseconds)
Is it not possible to bind datatable to gridview directly?

Comment: While appending your dynamically generated  html use native javascript like document.getElementById('gvRemarksHistory').appendChild(tempDataHtml); this will make it a bit faster then jquery.append()

Comment: @user1463065 ,you can use jquery virtual scrolling to get the solution of your problem...

Comment: I have another probelm here. Untill the completion of ajax call my page getting hanged means i can not access any controls on page. How to overcome this

Comment: You are using asynchronous ajax call so there should not be any problem of hang, but the problem is where you append your large html in to DOM, so try to reduce html.

Answer (score 0):

GridView is always to slow when load large amount of data on the page. Basically GridView is good option for small data. If you want to show large amount of data then you should use HTML table. It is contain more data and fast loading to page rather than GridView.
I hope you understand what can i say.

Comment: As per my understanding you mean to say instead of gridview i need to take html table <table id='tbl' runat="server"> and append the same data to table called tbl

Comment: Yes you can create html table using code. and fill data in this table.